# In C: take a user in put and create a number of variables based on that input

Tags: c, variables, user-input

I need to simulate an n-way cache in C. I have a fixed number of blocks and based on whatever level of associativity the user wants, I want to divide the cache into a number of sets based on that input. So for example, if I have 16 total blocks and they want 2-way associativity, I want to create 8 different arrays with 2 elements each. Is this possible in C or do I need to find another way to implement this?

Comment: Yes, this is doable in C.  Pick the right data structures and implement the appropriate operations on them.

Comment: You won't have N variables like `x1`, `x2`, `x3`.  You will probably have an *array* with elements `x[1]`, `x[2]`, `x[3]`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to manipulate fixed memory so your best bet is using pointers.

If the acceptable user inputs are finite, eg. 2,4,8 and 16, you could typedef 4 structs with 2,4,8 and 16 blocks.

```
typedef struct{
    int block;// replace type with appropriate block size
}Block;

typedef struct {
    Block b[2];
}TwoWay;

typedef struct {
    Block b[4];
}FourWay;

FourWay* p=&memory;
// Set0 - p
// Set1 - p+1
// Set2 - p+2 ...
```

You can manipulate number of pointers or number of increments based on user input.

Alternatively, just use pointers to manually jump to the memory location you need. Write an address resolution function that will point to a different location based on user input.